# Tournament with n players

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

A tournament consists of n players and all possible $C(n,2)= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pairwise matches between them. There are no ties in a match: in any match, one of the two players wins. The score of a player is the number of matches she wins out of all her $(n − 1)$ matches in the tournament. Denote the score vector of the tournament as $s \equiv (s_1, \ldots , s_n)$ and assume without loss of generality $s_1 ≥ s_2 ≥ . . . ≥ s_n$. It is also given that for any $2 \le k \le n$, $s_1 + . . . + s_k \ge C(k, 2),_\  where_\ C(k, 2) = \frac{k(k−1)}{2}$

(a). I want to show that suppose $s_n = s_0,_\ s_{n−1} = s_0 +1, s_{n−2} = s_0 +2 _\ for_\ some_\ positive_\ integer _\ s_0, n \ge 3$.
Then $$ s_0 \leq \frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2n}$$

(b). A tournament generate a score vector $s$ such that $$s_j -s_{j+1}=1_\  \forall j_\ \in {1,...,(n-1)}$$ What is the score vector in this tournament? For every player $j$, who does player $j$ beats in this tournament?

**My approach**

(a). We are given $3$ players with the lowest scores have scores $s_0 , s_0 +1, s_0 +2$. Since the remaining $n-3$ have the scores $ \geq s_0 +2$ therefore we can use the **formula for sum of first $n$ terms**. After that, I got stuck.

Comment: (b) forces $n=2$ with score vector $(1,0)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why?  With $n=3$ can you have $s_1=2,s_2=1,s_3=0$?

Comment: @Henry, when I wrote that, (b) had $s_j+s_{j+1}=1$ for all $j$. Now that has been edited to $s_j-s_{j+1}=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson my apologies about that, i rechecked the question and i've been trying to solve it w.r.t $s_j - s_{j+1}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose $s_n = x$ and $s_{n-i} = x+i$ then adding their score vector we get
$$nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac {n(n-1)}{2}$$

hence value of $x=0$. Therefore the score vector is $(s_1,..., s_n) = [ n-1, n-2,...0]$
Player $j$ beats all the players $i$ given that $i>j$